# Tiempo que demora la carga de una tabla con Datatables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

venia haciendo pruebas con una tabla con 2.000 registros y datatables funcionaba bien, ahora la cambie por otra que tiene 16.000 registros y después de 7 segundos da error.

En el depurador veo que el select se hizo completo (los 16.000 registros) lo que me da para pensar que es por el tiempo que demora la consulta...

tengo varias preguntas

Es posible cargar solo los primeros 50 registros y luego ir cargando mas a medida que el cliente cambie las paginas?

Es posible cambiar el tiempo de espera en datatables?

como acelerar la carga de los registros?

Gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Te recomiendo ir cargando en bloques o hacer paginación con tu tabla.

Comment: Viendo tus tags veo que utilizas php, por lo que una paginacion seria tu mejor opción, así lo limitas a la cantidad que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

> La cláusula LIMIT se puede usar para restringir el número de filas
>   devueltas por la instrucción SELECT. LIMIT toma uno o dos argumentos
>   numéricos, que deben ser constantes enteras no negativas.
>
> Con dos argumentos, el primer argumento especifica el desplazamiento
>   de la primera fila a devolver, y el segundo especifica el número
>   máximo de filas a devolver. El desplazamiento de la fila inicial es 0
>   (no 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Regresa 6-15
```